# Why can't I start the WinPCap npf service when I'm the administrator?

Tags: windows, permissions, wireshark, winpcap

I recently installed Wireshark on a Win 7 host, but now it won't let me start the NPF service.  I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net start npf
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

That's strange, because I am in the local admins group, and the SDDL string for the 'npf' service shows that the RP and WP permissions are allowed to the built-in administrator group.

```
C:\Windows\system32>net localgroup

Aliases for \\DOC

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*Administrators
*Backup Operators
*Cryptographic Operators
*Distributed COM Users
*Event Log Readers
*Guests
*IIS_IUSRS
*Network Configuration Operators
*Offer Remote Assistance Helpers
*Performance Log Users
*Performance Monitor Users
*Power Users
*Remote Desktop Users
*Replicator
*Users
The command completed successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>sc sdshow npf

D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCR
RC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)
```

Clearly I am missing something, but what?

Comment: WinPCap 4.1.2  I even un-installed and re-installed it.  Then, as the same user, failed to start it using "net start npf". :-(   McAfee is running on the machine, but isn't jumping up and down about stuff.

Comment: I even re-booted.  Same problem.

Comment: Altough it might not be the solution you want, have you tried something like `sc sdset (A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;YOUR_USER_SID)` assuming that it's not something silly like executing from the wrong user.
EDIT: And check your GPO

Comment: Relevant [http://serverfault.com/questions/55961/is-it-possible-to-use-group-policy-to-grant-the-permission-to-manage-windows-ser](http://serverfault.com/questions/55961/is-it-possible-to-use-group-policy-to-grant-the-permission-to-manage-windows-ser)

Comment: I can try assigning direct to a user, although I didn't want to have to (like you suspected).  Thanks for the link to the GPO info.  1am here ... a job for the morning, to be sure.  (edited)

Comment: Is that an elevated command window?  (If so, the title bar will say Administrator: cmd.exe instead of just cmd.exe.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're not running it from an elevated command prompt. From the GUI you can `click Start > Type cmd > right click > Run As Administrator` and try again.

From an unelevated command prompt you can do `runas /user:domain\user cmd`